# Why are my assets not loaded the way I want them to be - development mode. rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I am unsure if there is a setting in rails 4.2 that changed from 4.1, or if I am just crazy sauce. But this is my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require backbone

//= require app
//= require app/helpers/core.js
//= require app/collections/aisis_writer_user
//= require app/routers/aisis_writer_panel
//= require app/views/aisis_writer_panel
```

It clearly states exactly how my assets should be loaded. The are a couple of these file that have there own require statements at the top. Now in development mode, from how I see things is I do not get a giant concatenated file of assets, instead each asset is loaded as a script tag in the header of the page. That would be fine if it followed the order I have set out.

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/helpers/intervals.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/helpers/reset_intervals.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/routers/aisis_writer_panel.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/collections/aisis_writer_user.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/helpers/core.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/views/aisis_writer_panel.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/app/helpers/polling.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/react.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/react_ujs.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/backbone.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

This isn't how I specified things to be ordered at all, as a result I am getting:

```
uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
aisis_writer_user.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
aisis_writer_panel.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
backbone.js:219 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
```

The way I ordered things, these errors should not - or at least not all of them - be appearing.

So my question is: **Why is the asset pipeline ignoring me when I tell it to load files in a specific way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Why is the asset pipeline ignoring me when I tell it to load files in a specific way?**

It's not, it's doing exactly what you've asked it to. **You** are ignoring the big `require_tree .` in the middle of your `require` statements.

The whole point of `require_tree .` is that it recursively includes all the files it finds in the directory you give it. You're giving it `.`, so that that point you're going to be dumping every single `.js` or `.coffee` file in your `app/assets/javascripts` directory into your manifest, in whatever order they happen to be read from disk.

If you didn't want that behavior, you need to remove that line.